# How to test key and value of object using supertest module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, supertest

I have test code as below:

```
const mocha = require('mocha');
const describe = mocha.describe;
const it = mocha.it;
const chai = require('chai');
const request = require('supertest');

const app = require('../app.test');

chai.should();

describe('Get /histories', () => {
  it('should return 200 status code', done => {
    request(app)
      .get('/client/profile')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200, done);
  });

  it('should return code: 400', done => {
    request(app)
      .get('/client/profile')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200)
      .expect(res => {});
  });
});
```

And I respond with a custom status code using Express:

```
return res.json({
    code: 400
})
```

Therefore I want to test that test code has code as key of object and the value is 400 as number.

How can I write this test?

Comment: Did you try using the `res`ponse in that last `.expect` callback?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nope, I m newbie as unit tester. Could you wirte some code for me?

Comment: No, SO isn't a code-writing service. Look at the Supertest docs, they have examples of assertions on responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
it('should return code: 400', (done) => {
  request(app)
    .get('/client/profile')
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
    .expect(200)
    .end((err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      expect(res.code).to.be.equal(400);
      return done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. Let me know if you need more information.

```
it('should return code: 400', async (done) => {
    var resp = await request(app)
      .get('/client/profile')
      expect(resp.statusCode).to.equal(400)
      expect(resp.body.code).to.equal(400)
  });
```

`resp.statusCode` is the http response code.
`resp.body` is the response body. As that is a json, the response json of will have `code`.